# removing eventhandler seems not to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the next code (code does not run like copied here) that I would like to use for addressing errors on an input field of a form. The field is checked when the focus of the field is lost. An ajax request checks if the entry is allowed for that field (based on a lookup table). The two user functions set and remove error class around the input field.
When an error occurs, I want the field in error to have the only focus of the whole form (user has to correct this field before a different field is selected).
That last requirement does not work in the code. The focus is handed intermitted to the fields. It seems like if I have to click more then needed as well.

Question: What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var errors = [];
  //check value in lookup table with ajax
  $("body").on("blur", "input[data-table]", function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("id");
    var table = $("input[name=" + name + "]").data().table;
    var value = $(this).val();
    var len = value.length;
    //Only if an entry has been made in the field
    if (len > 0) {
      var jqxhr = $.post("/controller/lookup.php", {
        table: table,
        value: value
      }, function() {});
      //Done with the request 
      jqxhr.done(function(data) {
        var e = JSON.parse(data).error;
        if (e == "true") {
          //set error    
          setError(name);
          //prevent focus on other 
          $("body").on("click", "input", function(e) {
            if (!(e.target.id == name))
              $("input#" + name).focus();
          });
        } else {
          removeError(name);
          $("body").off("click", "input");
        }
      });
      //A failure has occured 
      jqxhr.fails(function(xhr, msg) {
        //TODO: exception handling        
      });
    }
    //if the field has been cleared remove error
    removeError(name);
  });

  function setError(name) {
    //Check if error already exists  
    if (!getErrors(name)) {
      var e = getErrorIndex(name);

      if (e > -1) errors[e].error = true;

      else errors.push({
        name: name,
        error: true
      });

      var span = "<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign\" style=\"color: red; float: left\"></span>";
      //Decorate errors
      $("input#" + name).parent().addClass("has-error");
      $("input#" + name).after(span);

    };
  }

  function removeError(name) {
    var e = getErrorIndex(name);
    if (e > -1) {

      errors[e].error = false;

      $("input#" + name).parent().removeClass("has-error");
      $("input#" + name).next().remove();
    }
  }

  function getErrors(needle) {
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
      if (errors[i].name === needle) return errors[i].error;
    }
    return false;
  }

  function getErrorIndex(needle) {
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
      if (errors[i].name === needle) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: did you tried with https://api.jquery.com/focus/

Comment: Yes, actually i am using the focus() method within in on("click) event